# eclipse: explicitly saving project / workspace

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to force Eclipse to save project / workspace settings? I can't find a "save workspace" or "save project" command.

(I've never had a problem with this in Eclipse, but TI's Code Composer 4 is based on Eclipse and it sometimes crashes and doesn't retain the changes I made in project settings.)

Answer (score 7):

The surest way to force such a save would be to switch workspace.

Switch to an empty workspace, and then switch back to your current workspace: every project settings should have been saved and restored.

Note: the [bug 27821 ([Workbench] saving state and preferences)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27821) is a duplicate of:
[bug 2369 ([Workbench] Would like to be able to save workspace without exiting)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=2369), which is opened since... 2001!
So even the "switching workspace" trick might not be enough to save *every* settings, but that is a start.

---

Edit September 2011:

[Aaron Digulla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34088/aaron-digulla) add in the comments he has added a **plugin 'saveui'** ([bug 337593](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337593), which duplicates [bug 2369](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=2369)), and which could be a good solution to save your workspace state (without having to close your Eclipse or switch your workspace).

To use this plugin, [download the code](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=189362), open the archive, copy the "dropins" folder into your "eclipse" folder (possibly merging with the existing dropins folder), close Eclipse, and re-open Eclipse. You should see a small lock-like icon in the toolbar, just below the menus. Clicking this icon is supposed to save the workspace.

Comment: I've attached a plugin to bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337593 which can save the UI state after every change.

Comment: @Aaron: excellent. I have included a reference to your 'saveui' plugin in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The place where is a workspace - workbranch is in 
`Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\`

You can use wakeup() method to force save workspace

```
  Job[] jobs = WorkbenchJob.getJobManager().find("WorkbenchAuto-Save Job");
  Job workspaceJob = Arrays.asList(jobs).get(0);
  workspaceJob.wakeUp();
```

Comment: um.... that's a programmatic method, I'm just using Eclipse interactively, not writing Java to make Eclipse do something.